# UWP ListView items not filling ListView's Width

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp

I have a ListView with a set width of 1000 and I would like the items to expand to fill this width if their width is set to 1000 or more.

All answers I have found yet suggest this

```
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

which is failing to do anything.

Here's the ListView code.

```
    <ListView Width="1000" Background="Violet">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="1000" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.Items>
            <x:String>ITEM1</x:String>
            <x:String>ITEM2</x:String>
        </ListView.Items>

    </ListView>
```

[image]

I tried ListBox and this behavior is present there as well. Apparently, the items can fill the original width minus 24 so, if I set my item's width to 976, it perfectly fills the container. Anymore and it gets hidden behind the container.

Thanks.

Comment: remove the Width parameter from the DataTemplate of ItemTemplate, set both the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch` instead of `Center` ; tell me what happens. I don't get what do you mean by "not filling ListView's width". Can you attach photos of your desired situation and current situation?

Comment: @Muzib Removing width from the template narrows it down to minimum width of item and both alignments don't actually do anything in this case. Martin's answer is correct that it is the default padding which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `ListViewItem` container has a padding, which is 12 epx from all sides. To remove it, set the property to 0 as well:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```